# How to position the text or a radio group's itemf?

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Input data</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_css.css">
</head>

<body style="position:relative; top=0px; left=0px;">
      <input type="radio" name="radio_name" value="one" checked>one<br>
      <input type="radio" name="radio_name" value="two">two<br>
      <input type="radio" name="radio_name" value="three">three<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

reset.css is one of the more famous one's (I forget where I got it, sorry).

The button text is appearing left aligned (behind the radio buttons), so what's the correct CSS to make it appear to the right of the buttons?

I am guessing something with `input[type="radio"]` and border or padding, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I have a hard time in visualizing your problem and how you need it to be. Please update your question to replace `<link>` by `<style>` containing the **minimum** CSS which still reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off, that isn't valid HTML - where did your opening `form` tag go?

To correct method for creating labels for form element is using the (surprise!) `label` element. If you need each element on separate lines it is recommended to use a list to separate each line. Something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="radio_name" value="one" id="one" checked><label for="one">one</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="radio_name" id="two" value="two"><label for="two">two</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="radio_name" id="three" value="three"><label for="three">three</label></li>
<ul>
```

This will look something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/e9WAn/)** without any CSS except for the reset. Otherwise there's nothing we can help you out with here unless you actually show us the CSS. Just guessing though, you might have set `position: absolute` on your `input` elements.

Here are some of the possible styles that may cause the problem you described: http://jsfiddle.net/3HUnL/